# GitLab CI - pg_dump error in pipeline stage

Tags: postgresql, gitlab-ci, pg-dump

gitlab-ci.yaml file:

```
liquibase:
   stage: liquibase
   image: openjdk:8-jre-alpine
   services:
      - postgres
   script:
      - INIT_PATH='pwd'
      - apk upgrade
      - apk add bash
      - apk add postgresql
      - cd migrations
      - mkdir /liquibase
      - mkdir /Downloads
      - cd /Downloads
      - wget "https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/releases/download/liquibase-parent-3.7.0-bin.zip"
      - wget "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.2.8/postgresql-42.2.8.jar"
      - unzip liquibase-3.7.0-bin.zip -d /liquibase -q
      - cd ../../liquibase
      - export PATH=$PATH:/liquibase
      - psql -h "postgres" -U "$POSTGRES_USER" -d "$POSTGRES_DB" -l
      - liquibase --changeLogFile=$INIT_PATH/migrations/baseline_postgres.xml --url="jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/custom_baseline" --username $POSTGRES_USER" -d "$POSTGRES_DB" -l
      - cd ../../..
      - pg_dump -h "postgres" -U "$POSTGRES_USER" -d "POSTGRES_DB" > baseline_schema.sql
```

This stage in my gitlab-ci pipeline (kubernetes executor) returns the following error:

```
pg_dump: server version: 13.1 (debian 13.1.1.pddg100+1); pg_dump version 11:10
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

I have tried adding symbolic links as other posts have suggested but I haven't succeeded. Any suggestions on resolving the pg_dump error for this stage in my Gitlab-CI pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `pg_dump` from the wrong PostgreSQL version. Change the `PATH`environment variable or use an absolute path.

Comment: I found the absolute path for pg_dump and updated the pg_dump command accordingly:

/usr/bin/pg_dump -h "postgres" -U "$POSTGRES_USER" -d "POSTGRES_DB" > baseline_schema.sql

I still receive the same error.

Comment: That's the wrong one. You have to use `pg_dump` from v13. If in doubt, uninstall v11.

Comment: I changed "services: -postgres" to "services: -postgres:11.10-alpine" and it worked.

Comment: Sure, using the v11 server will work too.